# How to record audio from each microphone on an android phone into separate files at the same time?

Tags: java, android, android-mediarecorder, android-audiorecord

In android studio I am able to create a mediaRecorder instance and record audio, I can then create an instance of a mediaRecorder with a different audio source and record audio. The problem is that I cannot have two mediaRecorders at one time (or so I think).

In addition to mediaRecorder, I have looked into using two different AudioRecord objects but it appears someone here tried that about a month ago and it does not work either. I have looked into the mediaMuxer which may be the key to this, but I am new to the concept of multiplexing and do not know how to implement something of this kind.

```
// not to professional standards  
btnRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(checkPermissionFromDevice()) {

                pathsave = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath() + "/"
                        + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + 
"_audio_record.3gp";
                setupMediaRecorder();
                try {
                    mediaRecorder.prepare();
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
                btnStop.setEnabled(false);
                btnStopRecord.setEnabled(true);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recording...", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    requestPermission();
                }
            }
        });

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

btnRecord2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(checkPermissionFromDevice()) {

                pathsave2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath() + "/"
                        + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + 
"_audio_record.3gp";
                setupMediaRecorder2();
                try {
                    mediaRecorder2.prepare();
                    mediaRecorder2.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                btnPlay2.setEnabled(false);
                btnStop2.setEnabled(false);
                btnStopRecord2.setEnabled(true);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recording...", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                requestPermission();
            }
        }
    });
 //-----------------------------------------------------------------------

 private void setupMediaRecorder() {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pathsave);

}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

private void setupMediaRecorder2() {
    mediaRecorder2 = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder2.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder2.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder2.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder2.setOutputFile(pathsave2);

}
```

I can record, stop recording and playback both media recorders separately. When I try to record both at the same time, the app crashes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK you can only use one instance of `MediaRecorder` at a time.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a new thread with another instance of MediaRecorder?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You can test this using your device's voice recorder, start recording then plug your earphones (with mic) in.